# Is this CSS even doing anything?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me with this?
I am currently struggling with understanding relative positioning and whether or not it is good practice to use absolute positioning. During my trials, I did this with my code and I am completely unaware of whether or not this code is even doing anything

```
/* Parent Styling */
.center {
  width:333px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Here is my HTML and full CSS as well

```css
/* Parent Styling */

.center {
  width: 333px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Center 404 Styling */

.c-main-text {
  animation: broken 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  width: 333px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #2B2C30;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 200px;
}

@keyframes broken {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    margin-top: 410px;
  }
}


/* Center Top text Styling */

.c-top-text {
  width: 302px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #2B2C30;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p class="c-top-text">Uh oh... something went wrong!</p>
  <p class="c-main-text">404</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The simplest way of telling if something is doing anything is to take a screenshot, comment the code out, then reload and take another screenshot. If you can't tell the difference between the screenshots, it's probably not doing anything. Considering all of the definitions you have on the child elements, it's unlikely the parent CSS is doing much. You could get rid of a lot of the child CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you read this well-written [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on Mozilla about position.
Ask for your code, The .c-main-text and c-top-text will adjust their positions base on the .center class because absolute is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor which is .center